# ciclo for studio 5000

Tags: bucle-for

soy nuevo en el mundo de programacion, estoy ejecutando este Ciclo For en Texto structurado PLC RSLOGIX 5000 pero me arroja valores extraños apartir de las tercias, anexo codigo
Gracias por su apoyo y tiempo
saludos

```
**PARES := 0;
RESULT_PARES:=0;
TERCIAS := 0;
RESULT_TERCIAS := 0;
CUARTAS := 0;
RESULT_CUARTAS := 0;
QUINTAS := 0;
RESULT_QUINTAS:= 0;

**FOR PARES:=2 TO 100  BY 2 DO
            RESULT_PARES := RESULT_PARES + PARES;
                FOR TERCIAS := 3 TO 97 BY 3 DO
                RESULT_TERCIAS:= RESULT_TERCIAS + TERCIAS;
                END_FOR;
                    FOR CUARTAS := 4 TO 96 BY 4 DO
                    RESULT_CUARTAS := RESULT_CUARTAS + CUARTAS;
                    END_FOR;
                        FOR QUINTAS := 5 TO 95 BY 5 DO
                        RESULT_QUINTAS := RESULT_QUINTAS + QUINTAS;
                        END_FOR;
        END_FOR;****
```

Comment: que serian `valores extraños`? que relacion tiene la pregunta con c# ?

Comment: Hola ya quedo resulto, debido a que los ciclos faltaban una condicion de un if, quedo de la siguiente manera

Answer (score 0):

```
Hola quedo resuelto de la siguiente manera:
```

**

```
PARES := 0;
RESULT_PARES:=0;
TERCIAS := 0;
RESULT_TERCIAS := 0;
CUARTAS := 0;
RESULT_CUARTAS := 0;
QUINTAS := 0;
RESULT_QUINTAS:= 0;
            FOR PARES:=2 TO 100  BY 2 DO
                RESULT_PARES := RESULT_PARES + PARES;   
                IF PARES >= TERCIAS THEN
                    FOR TERCIAS := 3 TO 100 BY 3 DO
                        RESULT_TERCIAS:= RESULT_TERCIAS + TERCIAS;
                    END_FOR;
                END_IF;
                    IF PARES >= CUARTAS THEN
                        FOR CUARTAS := 4 TO 100 BY 4 DO
                            RESULT_CUARTAS := RESULT_CUARTAS + CUARTAS;
                        END_FOR;
                    END_IF;
                        IF PARES >= QUINTAS THEN
                            FOR QUINTAS := 5 TO 100 BY 5 DO
                                RESULT_QUINTAS := RESULT_QUINTAS + QUINTAS;
                            END_FOR;
                        END_IF;
            END_FOR;
```

**